# Pandas: Top n of group, and top n of those groups

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
entry_1 = pd.Series({'State': 'State1', 'County': 'name1', 'Population': 10})
entry_2 = pd.Series({'State': 'State1', 'County': 'name12', 'Population': 8})
entry_3 = pd.Series({'State': 'State1', 'County': 'name13', 'Population': 7})
entry_4 = pd.Series({'State': 'State1', 'County': 'name14', 'Population': 6})
entry_5 = pd.Series({'State': 'State2', 'County': 'name15', 'Population': 10})
entry_6 = pd.Series({'State': 'State2', 'County': 'name16', 'Population': 8})
entry_7 = pd.Series({'State': 'State2', 'County': 'name17', 'Population': 7})
entry_8 = pd.Series({'State': 'State2', 'County': 'name18', 'Population': 6})
entry_9 = pd.Series({'State': 'State3', 'County': 'name19', 'Population': 10})
entry_10 = pd.Series({'State': 'State3', 'County': 'name10', 'Population':8})
entry_11 = pd.Series({'State': 'State3', 'County': 'name11', 'Population':7})
entry_12 = pd.Series({'State': 'State3', 'County': 'name12', 'Population':6})
entry_13 = pd.Series({'State': 'State4', 'County': 'name13', 'Population':1})
entry_14 = pd.Series({'State': 'State4', 'County': 'name14', 'Population':2})
entry_15 = pd.Series({'State': 'State4', 'County': 'name15', 'Population':3})
df = pd.DataFrame([
    entry_1, entry_2,entry_3,entry_4,entry_5,entry_6,entry_7,
    entry_8,entry_9,entry_10,entry_11,entry_12, entry_13, entry_14, entry_15])
df.head()
```

> Using the three most populous counties within a state, I need to find
>   the three most populous states, in order of highest population to
>   lowest.

I have made an attempt that I thought makes sense, although I am not getting the expected result. I could not replicate this with the example code, but I am thinking maybe there are missing values, or something similar which is throwing the calculation off..

```
df['SUM_OF_TOP'] = df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3).sum(level=1)
largest_States = df['SUM_OF_TOP'].nlargest(3).index
[df.loc[idx]['State'] for idx in largest_States]
>>> ['State1', 'State2', 'State3']
```

Any recommendations as to what might be wrong? I have only just started with Pandas, so I'm quite clueless..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do this:

```
In [69]: df.loc[8, 'Population'] = 11

In [70]: df.loc[[5,6], 'Population'] = 9

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
    County  Population   State
0    name1          10  State1
1   name12           8  State1
2   name13           7  State1
3   name14           6  State1
4   name15          10  State2
5   name16           9  State2  # changed Population value: 8 --> 9
6   name17           9  State2  # changed Population value: 7 --> 9
7   name18           6  State2
8   name19          11  State3  # changed Population value: 10 --> 11
9   name10           8  State3
10  name11           7  State3
11  name12           6  State3
12  name13           1  State4
13  name14           2  State4
14  name15           3  State4

In [72]: df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0).nlargest(3).index.tolist()
Out[72]: ['State2', 'State3', 'State1']

In [73]: df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
Out[73]:
State
State1    25
State2    28
State3    26
State4     6
Name: Population, dtype: int64
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
In [80]: df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(3).sum(level=0).sort_values(ascending=0).head(3).index
Out[80]: Index(['State2', 'State3', 'State1'], dtype='object', name='State')
```

Comment: This is returning the same output I was getting.. but after your last edit I think maybe I need to add a sort ?

Comment: @Giannis, can you post a __desired__ data set?

Comment: This is through an online course I am doing, they are using some census data which I don't have direct access to. Wondering if I need to add a sort somewhere, I though nlargest will return sorted data but on your last snippet the states are not sorted..

Comment: @Giannis, `nlargest()` - returns sorted data set, but `.sum(level=0)` - doesn't

Comment: Ok thank you, will try and figure out what's off with this new info !

Comment: What's really funny is that a coworker of mine came to me with this same problem. It's a homework assignment where they are using US census data.

Comment: I cleared some leftover code outside function and all answers are now accepted... Yes this is for a coursera course. I am on the free version so I am not sure if I get blocked for failing the assignment or not, but its quite interesting so far.

Answer (score 2):

[This was my answer to this question on code review:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151530/126629)

[`SUMLEV` is explained here](http://blog.cubitplanning.com/2011/03/census-summary-level-sumlev/)

Definitely want to use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)
The advantage of `nlargest` is that it performs a partial sort therefore in linear time.

However, you don't want to `groupby` twice.  So we'll define a helper function in which we only `groupby` once.

I'm using a lot of `.values` to access underlying `numpy` objects.  This will improve some efficiency a bit.

Lastly, I don't like accessing names from the outer scope without a purpose so I'm passing the dataframe as a parameter.

```
def answer_six(df):
    # subset df to things I care about
    sumlev = df.SUMLEV.values == 50
    data = df[['CENSUS2010POP', 'STNAME', 'CTYNAME']].values[sumlev]

    # build a pandas series with State and County in the index
    # vaues are from CENSUS2010POP
    s = pd.Series(data[:, 0], [data[:, 1], data[:, 2]], dtype=np.int64)

    # define a function that does the nlargest and sum in one
    # otherwise you'd have to do a second groupby
    def sum_largest(x, n=3):
        return x.nlargest(n).sum()

    return s.groupby(level=0).apply(sum_largest).nlargest(3).index.tolist()
```

***Demonstration***

```
answer_six(census_df)

['California', 'Texas', 'Illinois']
```

Comment: That's the list of answers I get,  still marked as wrong.

Comment: I even did a very simplistic solution that has been provided in psedocode by the course admin, which gives the same result as my previous code. I have already passed the assignment, but its just very annoying why its not working. https://gist.github.com/latusaki/d56584ed5ba3e2caa921caa58d162d50

Comment: Thanks for the feedback in any case, and helpful commnets I will see if there are any leftovers in other questions which are causing the marker to fail.

Comment: @Giannis did admin provide code solution or list they claim is accurate

Comment: A course admin has provided this pseudocode: https://gist.github.com/latusaki/d56584ed5ba3e2caa921caa58d162d50#file-psedo-txt